# On form submit add form values to table

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have the following form in my view:

```
    @using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "doneInternalAddressBook" }))
    {
         @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)
         @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)
         @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId)
         <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
              <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { id = "SelectedAddressBookPerson", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in AddressBook..." }) 

                   <input type='submit' id="btnAddressBook" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>">
              </div>
          </div>               
    }
```

And this table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tableAttendees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Whenever the form is submitted, I want to add the values from the form (first name, last name, email, etc) to the table. What should I do to able to do that?

Controller method

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook(CreateAppointmentSelectPersons internalAddressbookPerson)
    {
        _attendeeRepository.AddInternalAddressBookAttendee(
            internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId,
            internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName,
            internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName,
            internalAddressbookPerson.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email);

    }
```

I could also add a function that returns form value as json data for the table but that would mean going back to database and loading the data, also the table should be updated each time a user submits a form or some values are added to database could be a performance problem? I think having jquery function to push form values to table would be better idea, but then I don't have much knowledge about jquery(just a beginner)

```
public ActionResult AttendeeTableData(Guid appointmentId)
{
    var attendees = _attendeeRepository.GetAttendees(appointmentId);
    return Json(attendees);
}
```

Edit1:
this is what i tried to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function () {

        $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
            source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event,ui) {
                $(@Html.IdFor((m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName))).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
            },
        });

    });
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAddressBook").on('click', function () {
            $("#form2").submit(function () {
                var fields = $(":input");
                jquery.each(fields, function (i, field) {
                    $("#tableAttendees").find('tbody tr:last').append("<td>" + field.value + "</td>")
                });
            })
        })
    });

</script>
```

but this doesn't work

Edit 2:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "doneInternalAddressBook" }))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId)
     <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
          <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { id = "SelectedAddressBookPerson", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in AddressBook..." })                         
               <input type='submit' id="btnAddressBook" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>">
          </div>
      </div>               
} 

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tableAttendees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>       
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js")

    <script id ="personTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr>
            <th>${FirstName}</th>
            <th>${LastName}</th>
            <th>${Email}</th>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnAddressBook").click(function (e) {
                var model = new Object();

                model.FirstName = $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)).val();
                model.LastName = $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)).val();
                model.Email = $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email)).val();

                $("#personTmpl").tmpl(model).appendTo("#tableAttendees");
            })
        })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(function () {

            $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
                source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event,ui) {
                    $(@Html.IdFor((m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName))).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                    $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
                },
            });

        });   
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Are these two components generated in the same page?

Comment: Can you show us your Controller Action code?

Comment: @AndreiV yes its is same page, the idea is you add peoples to your appointment, every time user adds person to his appointment, he can see list of peoples he has added in a table next to it.

Comment: @ramiramilu I don't think i need to show my controller code, I just need to add those forms value to table. A jquery function maybe? but if you want to see the controllers code i can add it

Comment: @Biplov13, I wanted to know if you controller action is returning what data, partial view or json data? And can we use that bind that data to div using jquery? I asked it just for that cause. Anyways I will try to solve it with mere jquery and post it as answer to you.

Comment: @ramiramilu i'll add more detailed information may be then you can help

Comment: @ramiramilu i have updated the question may be you can have a look now

Comment: @Biplov13 Now you don't need the `onclick` event. That was my first answer. Return the input to be of type `submit` and try again.

Comment: @Biplov13 I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes one more answer by using JQuery Templates -

First reference following JQuery libraries -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then create the template which you want to fill up with details -

```
<script id="personsTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <th>${FirstName}</th>
        <th>${LastName}</th>
        <th>${Email}</th>
    </tr>
</script>
```

As a next step define the Table in html -

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tableAttendees">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Have a submit button on the page -

```
<input type="submit" value="click" id="click" />
```

Finally handle the JQuery Click event of the Submit button -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#click').click(function (e) {
            var model = new Object();

            // Here you need to get the values using $('#id').val() and fill the model
            model.FirstName = "Rami";
            model.LastName = "Vemula";
            model.Email = "Email@E.com";

            $("#personsTmpl").tmpl(model).appendTo("#tableAttendees");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now when you run the application, and click on the submit button, you will see the values getting appending to the table as below -

[image]

Comment: so my Ajax form remains as it is? and i have to add the js codes you mentioned?

Comment: @Biplov13, yes that should be enough.

Comment: will give it a shot then let you know what happens

Comment: the submit button...isn't that the submit button inside the form?

Comment: @Biplov13, it is the submit button inside the form.

Comment: doesn't work, i have added the things i did in `edit2` I was expecting the table to be loaded before the form gets submitted, but then i called called to controller's function when i click the `Add>>` button without table being loaded

Comment: @Biplov13, In your `Edit2`, I do not see `#tableAttendees`. Also can you use alert() and see if you model object is being populated correctly. Also you missed `#` for btnAddressBook for jquery click.

Comment: I had #table attendees, just forgot to add, you can see the edit 2 now, oh damn, i added the #in btn will check it and update you

Comment: @Biplov13, Also you missed # before btnAddressBook for jquery click.

Comment: still doesn't work, i get forwarded to controller's method before table data being added, should it add table row before it calls the controller? I also, added # for the btnAddressBook. And, how do i use alert? inside my click function or model? Sorry don't know much about front end part

Comment: @Biplov13, `should it add table row before it calls the controller?` Yes. Just use alert($(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)).val());

Comment: when i do alert it shows the name for example firstname as biplov, but it doesn't add to the table

Comment: @Biplov13, do you get any errors in Chrome Console (use F12 Developer tools)? Check them.

Comment: Oh Man :-), What you did and got it working? And I think my answer do also need a upvote (just kidding), for all the comment thread we have been through!!!

Comment: I did a upvote for your answer, i just was giving wrong id for email thats why it wasn't working. Now the problem is my ajax form's onsuccess method is not calling the method i'm expecting. need to check on that. Anyways cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok updating my answer now that I better understood your question :)

First we take the inputs:

```
var fields = $( ":input" );
```

Then we iterate over them and add to table.

```
jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {     

    $("#tableAttendees").find('tbody tr:last') //this appends the data you want to the table
       .append("<td>" + field.value + "</td>");
});
```

And overall you get:

```
$("#form2").submit(function() {
     var fields = $( ":input" );
     jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {             
            $("#tableAttendees")
             .find('tbody tr:last') //this appends the data you want   to the table
             .append("<td>" + field.value + "</td>");
     });
});
```

Here's a link to JS [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waaAL/):

Comment: sorry but where is the value being added to table?

Comment: @Biplov13 You're right, I misunderstood your question. Will try to update soon

Comment: @Biplov13 Updated my answer. Hope it helps now.

Comment: sorry i'm totally newbie to jquery and javascript, i'm guessing `#AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook` is name of form and inside the submit function i set the values of form in `var fields` then do `jquery.each` to add values to table. All inside submit function?

Comment: @Biplov13 Yes, I regarded `AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook` as the name of your form. Inside the `submit` function, the code you write will be executed before the submission, so there if you add the code I wrote it will do the trick.

Comment: @Biplov13 Added a link to fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @Biplov13 Updated my answer so you can take the code straight from here. Please make sure the name of your form is `form2` and I don't see a reason this shouldn't work :)

Comment: Sorry, I chose the other answer, but +1 for help.